# Stuck on level 8 of VIM Adventures

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm stuck on the "Here's an easy game to play" puzzle. I feel like I need either the <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>#</kbd> keys, but all I have are:

[image: Screenshot of the keyboard in the puzzle]

Help please! Did I miss getting <kbd>n</kbd> somehwere?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same keyboard.  (This is *level 8* of Vim Adventures, for anyone who's not sure.)

- Enter the puzzle at `H` in `Here's`.
- Press `$`, end up at `y` in `easy`.
- Press `**`, end up at `e` in `easy` on the bottom.
- Press `jj`, end up on the grass below the "Here's an easy game to play" puzzle.
- Find the `#` key in the "You have brains in your head" puzzle.

> (Look in the bushes.)

[image: The "#" key is in the "brains in your head" puzzle.]

- Return to the "Here's an easy game to play" puzzle.
- Use a combination of `*` , `#` , `gg` , `0` , `^` , `f` , `b` , `e` to navigate the puzzle.
- When you have visited all the cracked tiles (thereby repairing them), a blue key will appear.
  [image: The key to the blue door is in the "Here's an easy game to play" puzzle.]
- Fetch the blue key, then go to the house with the blue door.  Use a combination of `#` , `*` , `e` , `f` , `gg` ,`j` , `$` to get there.
- The `n` key is behind the blue door.
  [image: Open the blue door to get the N key.]

If that doesn't make it clear, let me know and I can be more specific.  Enjoy.  :)

Comment: How can I visit the center cracked 'w'? I'm in 'w' on the center left. (Who)

Answer (score 0):

Go south through the easy game to play and you will find #. Think search.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I haven't played this game, but this doesn't make any sense to me at all. Is it possible to elaborate on this?